# How to count with multiple criteria in excel looking for the latest entry in a column

Tags: excel

I am looking to count the unique entries in a column in excel
counting only the ones with the highest date for that entry 
that have a specific value

```
the below is an example 
a   b           c
111 01/01/2015  dave 
121 01/12/2015  hayley
114 01/01/2015  james
111 01/12/2015  john
131 01/06/2015  peter
114 01/12/2015  james
192 01/01/2015  scooby
```

[image: example]

So for 111 I only want to count entry against john 
114 are both against James but I only want to count the 01/12/2015 entry

I am interested in how many unique entries each person has where the latest entry is against that person

Comment: The above is an example so I would have 6 statements- one for each name in C
I need to know what query I would use to find how many unique entries in A where B is the highest date are against that name

Comment: @pnuts I have been racking my brain on this for a few hours and have not come up with anything either, without using a few helper columns.

Comment: @pnuts and OP, the way I understand it, he wants to look at each number in column A, e.g. 111, find all the duplicates, then find the latest, or newest, by the dates in column B.  That is who gets the +1 in the count so in the end Dave would have 0, because John got credit since his was later.  I just don't see how to do this in one formula without writing a UDF to do it. but there may be others that have more experience.

Comment: @pnuts that is probably the best option.  I just don't think it is possible with a single formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, I do not believe it is possible without vba.  Here is a User Defined Function.

```
Function countmax(nme As Range, cntrng As Range) As String
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim t
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim arr

    arr = cntrng.Value2

    With cntrng
        a = Range(Cells(.Row, Columns(1).Column), Cells(.Rows(.Rows.Count).Row, Columns(1).Column)).Address
        b = Range(Cells(.Row, Columns(2).Column), Cells(.Rows(.Rows.Count).Row, Columns(2).Column)).Address
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 3) = nme Then
            t = Evaluate("= MAX(IF(" & a & "=" & Cells(i, 1).Address & "," & b & "))")
            If arr(i, 1) & t = arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) Then
                temp = temp + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    countmax = temp

End Function
```

It needs to be placed in a macro page tied to the workbook.

[image]

From Excel hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>.  In that window goto Insert ==> Module.  Into that module paste the above code.

[Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) is a better explanation with pictures.

It can be called directly from the worksheet.  For example if the list of names is in E2:E7 then in F2 put:

```
=countmax(E2,$A$1:$C$7)
```

For dave it would return `0` all the others would get `1`.

If you pasted the code in another workbook like the personal.xlsb then you need to preface the call:

```
=PERSONAL.XLSB!countmax(E2,$A$1:$C$7)
```

Comment: Thanks for you efforts guys this is beyond my ability, unfortunately it is not working and i am just getting a #NAME?

Comment: @craigbooth Did you put it in a module? Not in the workbook or worksheet code?

Comment: thanks, i have done that and still it is not working, however i guess it could be due to coulmn a being a sting ?
When i change the contents of a it no longer displays #VALUE! it shows 0 when i am expecting 1 - also if i remove the name from E a 0 is still displayed ?

Comment: It works for me with the data you provided.  Can you send me a copy of your workbook, scott.craner@gmail.com.  I realize that at times the data is different than the example and that could be causing the problem.  A couple things I thought of: make sure the dates are actual dates and not text.  It will not work if the dates are text.

Comment: Thanks Scott works a treat, exactly what i was after. Cheers

Comment: @craigbooth may I ask why the removal of the "Correct Answer"?

Comment: i didnt realize that i had, i thought i had ticked it as being correct but must have unticked it.